# Cell Alignment using ExcelApplication

Tags: officewriter

I am using ExcelApplication, not ExcelTemplate - so I'm programmatically doing a slight bit of formatting so it's just a super plain excel sheet - however, I presume my end-user would like to do formatting on their own so I'm keeping it light.

My header row is larger than other rows by measure of height:

```
        foreach (Worksheet ws in book)
        {
            ws.GetRowProperties(0).Height = 25; // this works
            ws.GetRowProperties(0).Style.VerticalAlignment = Style.VAlign.Center; // this has no effect
        }
```

I have attempted to apply cell alignment in several different ways by now, and I can't seem to ever have an end result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt with this by creating an `Area` and then Applying a style to said Area:

```
Area headerArea;
Style headerAreaStyle = book.CreateStyle();
headerAreaStyle.VerticalAlignment = Style.VAlign.Center;
headerAreaStyle.HorizontalAlignment = Style.HAlign.Center;
headerAreaStyle.Font.Size = 13;

foreach (Worksheet ws in book)
{
    switch (ws.Name)
    {
        case ("First Sheet"):
            headerArea = ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, 2);
            headerArea.SetRowHeight(0, 20);
            headerArea.ApplyStyle(headerAreaStyle);
            break;
        case ("Second Sheet"):
            headerArea = ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, 5);
            headerArea.SetRowHeight(0, 20);
            headerArea.ApplyStyle(headerAreaStyle);
            break;
        case ("Third Sheet"):
            headerArea = ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, 3);
            headerArea.SetRowHeight(0, 20);
            headerArea.ApplyStyle(headerAreaStyle);
            break;
        case ("Fourth Sheet"):
            headerArea = ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, 3);
            headerArea.SetRowHeight(0, 20);
            headerArea.ApplyStyle(headerAreaStyle);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are other -- and better -- ways to do this, but it works just fine for me.

Note that the `Switch` here is completely irrelevant to anyone but me. There are ways of doing in a more dynamic fashion, but these exports are static in terms of column numbers.